# Merging Django-CMS Edit and Publish Mode created two different Database entries with the same values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cms, web-development-server

My CTO asked me to fix an "issue."

Apparently, whenever I add any plugin in the locally run DRF-based Django CMS project, it creates two database entries. One for edit mode, and the other when I hit publish.

[image: Database Table looks like this for a single plugin]

My CTO asked to find if there were **any way to dynamically merge the edit mode entry with the merge mode and vice versa** when switching between those modes.

**Our website is very heavy. But is doing this even necessary for Django-CMS?**

Here is the model.py code for an example plugin.

Models.py:

```
class TechnologyVideo(ck_CMSPlugin):
    Video_thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to="technology_video", null=True, blank=True)
    video_url = models.URLField(help_text='Please enter your video url', validators=[URLValidator], null=True)
    # video_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, )
    # video_description = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True, configuration="VIDEO_POST_TEXT_CKEDITOR")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Technology Video Model"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return f'{self.Video_thumb}'
```

cms_plugins.py:

```
class TechnologyVideoPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = TechnologyVideo
    name = 'Technology Video Plugin'
    render_template = 'technology_video.html'

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({
            'Video_thumb': instance.Video_thumb,
            'video_url': instance.video_url,
        })
        context = super(TechnologyVideoPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context
        
    plugin_pool.register_plugin(TechnologyVideoPlugin)
```

Comment: There's no issue here. That's how the CMS works. It has a draft version and a live version for all content. The live version is what your visitors will see, and when you publish the draft version it's copied over to the live version.

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue here. That's how the CMS works.

It has a draft version and a live version for all content. The live version is what your visitors will see, and when you publish the draft version it's copied over to the live version.